# SQL bigint array column contain any member of another array?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, where-clause

In my schema, I have supply_source as `bigint[]`.

I would like to query for all rows in mytable that have **either** 123 or 456 in its supply_sources.

When I use this query, I am only getting rows that have **both 123 and 456** as its supply_source.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable  
WHERE supply_source = ARRAY[123, 456]::bigint[]
LIMIT 10;
```

How should I modify my query?

Comment: Select the proper database which is applicable.

Comment: I removed the [tag:mysql] tag, since MySQL does not have an array data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array overlap operator `&&`:

```
WHERE supply_source && ARRAY[123, 456]::bigint[]
```